# Validar si un registro existe en una tabla SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Cordial Saludo,

Lo que deseo hacer es validar si un registro existe en una tabla con un procedimiento almacenado desde SQL SERVER.

```
USE [BDCredito]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_CONS_SOLCUPO_APRO_EXISTE]    Script Date: 11/15/2018 08:48:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CONS_SOLCUPO_APRO_EXISTE]
(
@Id_Solicitud nvarchar (255),
@CC_Asociado nvarchar (255)
)
AS 
SELECT * FROM TBL_DOC_APRO WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TBL_DOC_APRO WHERE Id_Solicitud = ''+@Id_Solicitud+'' and CC_Asociado = ''+@CC_Asociado+'');
```

No se como hacer que eso funcione, espero me ayuden.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Que es lo que esperas que retorne el Sp?

Comment: No se bien cual sea tu requerimiento, pero si lo que necesitas es que se inserten o registren duplicados, una llave primaria o un unique constraint te pueden ayudar y te evitarias toda el problema de programarlos, ya seria cuestion de ver la logica de la aplicacion unicamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para empezar no debes poner comillas en las variables, ya llegan como texto, el concatenado es innecesario.

Puedes validar si existe y regresar un booleano, el cast as bit es para forzar el retorno de bit y no de un int. (causa conflicto en algunos ORM si no se especifica)

También podrías considerar poner esto mejor como función ya que no realiza ningún procedimiento de modificación a la base de datos.

```
USE [BDCredito]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CONS_SOLCUPO_APRO_EXISTE]
(
@Id_Solicitud nvarchar (255),
@CC_Asociado nvarchar (255)
)
AS 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TBL_DOC_APRO WHERE Id_Solicitud = @Id_Solicitud and CC_Asociado = @CC_Asociado)
    RETURN CAST(1 AS bit);
ELSE 
    RETURN CAST(0 AS bit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Haría solo un `SELECT COUNT(*)`de la tabla si te devuelve `0` no existe si te devuelve otra cosa quiere decir que si existe. Si solo se manejan registros únicos bajo esas condiciones, entonces puedo utilizar la respuesta de **shop350** si lo que deseas es un `bool` como respuesta en tu aplicación. O en su defecto también se puede hacer un `case` si se obtienen muchos registros en la consulta y convertir en base a esa respuesta a un `bool`. Donde `@Resultado`es una variable de salida.

Primera alternativa (Devuelve el número de registros que cumplen con la condición):

```
USE [BDCredito]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CONS_SOLCUPO_APRO_EXISTE]
(
@Id_Solicitud nvarchar (255),
@CC_Asociado nvarchar (255),
@Resultado int output
)
AS 
SELECT @Resultado = COUNT(*) FROM TBL_DOC_APRO
WHERE Id_Solicitud = @Id_Solicitud
AND CC_Asociado = @CC_Asociado;
```

Segunda alternativa (Si solo se obtiene 1 registro como respuesta devuelve un `bool`):

```
USE [BDCredito]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CONS_SOLCUPO_APRO_EXISTE]
(
@Id_Solicitud nvarchar (255),
@CC_Asociado nvarchar (255),
@Resultado bit output
)
AS 
SELECT @Resultado = CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIT) FROM TBL_DOC_APRO
WHERE Id_Solicitud = @Id_Solicitud
AND CC_Asociado = @CC_Asociado;
```

Tercera alternativa (Si se obtienen varios registros se realiza un `case` para convertir la respuesta en `bool`):

```
USE [BDCredito]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CONS_SOLCUPO_APRO_EXISTE]
(
@Id_Solicitud nvarchar (255),
@CC_Asociado nvarchar (255),
@Resultado bit output
)
AS 
SELECT @Resultado = CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) FROM TBL_DOC_APRO
WHERE Id_Solicitud = @Id_Solicitud
AND CC_Asociado = @CC_Asociado;
```

Las comillas simples no es necesario que lo coloques.